# Loading large amount (around 200GB) of rasters into mosaic dataset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, mosaic

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0

I have four folders with raster data over an area of approximately 8000 square km. Two folders contain rasters with 0.25 cell size (x and y), and two folders have 0.5 cell size.

I have tried loading into a mosaic dataset with the same coordinate system, and everything turned on.
What it looks like is this:

[image]

ArcGIS Pro is working for a bit, then gives me a result that gives all the footprints, but no overview. In addition, the range is between 123.386 meter and 123.085 meter. It should be around 1000 meter difference.

[image]

Everything is white.

As this tool modifies the input data, have I "destroyed" the data, and need to get fresh ones and load with other options?

Comment: What you see is normal, just zoom in and query raster. Nothing happened to original, mosaic is just a smart table pointing to originals.

Comment: I think that the only modifications to the input data would be where you've elected to build pyramids (and calculate statistics), and these can easily be rebuilt afterwards (or deleted), if you wish, without affecting the original source data.

Comment: My rule of thumb with rasters in ArcGIS (ArcMap and ArcPro, both), is to NEVER allow a tool to automatically build pyramids nor overviews.  By default, it uses "nearest neighbour" algorithm for these, and ArcGIS nearest neighbour method often results in pyramids/overviews that are corrupted, or don't display completely, or sometimes don't display at all.  Try deleting all pyramids, then doing it again with both these options turned off.  Then afterwards, build overviews and be sure to select the "Cubic" option and NOT the "nearest neighbour" option.

Comment: ... (I don't know why ESRI can't/won't fix this decades old bug).  So this MAY be related to your issue.  Worth a try.  (Does not explain the incorrect range of values though!)

Comment: (Note that you probably don't need both pyramids and overviews.  For a Mosaic, I use only overviews.  I only use Pyramids if I want to view the rasters separately - ie, without using the mosaic).

Comment: When you built the mosaic dataset did you use the correct pixel type and band number? did you set the cell size ranges? IMO nearest neighbor is fine for overviews because you're only *looking* at them and not *using them to derive data*, when viewing the data is being translated through a renderer to 8 bit unsigned which does far worse than the difference between bilinear/cubic to the values. As @SonofaBeach indicates both overviews and pyramids is a bit of a waste of space and time. I've seen this happen when the mosaic dataset is being viewed over a network and the paths aren't relative.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - my problem with Nearest Neighbour is that it doesn't even work reliably for looking at (visualizing) the raster.  Often it will work fine, but sometimes it results in a view of the raster that has bits missing, and in some cases, displays a complete blank (possibly like in this case).  Using Cubic always resolved such issues in my experience.